# encoding floats and integers in string

Tags: c++

I'm writing a C++ program that requires the encoding of some values in a string (it has to be a string). I decided to do it using sprintf to save the data (one unsigned int and two doubles) in a char array. The thing is that I am having problem understanding the behaviour of this function. Here is the code I am using

```
    char vel[1];
    unsigned int n = 30;
    std::sprintf(vel, "%u", n);
    std::cout<< "packet sending: " << vel << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "packet dim: " << sizeof(vel)<< std::endl;
```

This is a preliminary test. Since an unsigned int is 4 bytes and I am allocating an array only of 1 char (byte) I am expecting a segmentation fault However I am surprisingly (for me, of course) getting the output

```
packet sending: 30
packet dim: 4
```

Actually I do not understand why. Moreover the objective is to store three values of and retrieve them with scanf. Here is what I would like to do, if possible

```
    char vel[1];
    unsigned int n = 30;
    std::sprintf(vel, "%u%f%f", n, 5.0,6.0);
    std::cout<< "packet sending: " << vel << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "packet dim: " << sizeof(vel)<< std::endl;
```

and in another function once I sent the string

```
std::string s = vel.str();
```

I do

```
unsigned int i;
float g,h;
std::sscanf(s.c_str(), "%u%f%f",&i,&g,&h);
```

Of course nothing is working, could you please help me? I read the documentation of the used function but I couldn't understand why this is not working.
Thank you!
Andrea

EDIT: 
I run some tests, if I generate a string with the following code:

```
    char vel[13];
    unsigned int n = 30;
    std::sprintf(vel, "%u%f", n, 5.0); 
    std::stringstream packet;
    packet << vel;
    std_msgs::String outMsg;
    outMsg.data = packet.str();
```

and I try to retrieve the informations  in this way:

```
packet = msg->data.c_str();
unsigned int i;
float f;
std::sscanf(packet, "%u%f", &i, &f);
std::cout << "received packet: "<< i << "\tdata: "<< f << std::endl;
```

the print generated is

```
received packet: 305    data: 0
```

It should be

```
received packet: 30     data: 5
```

shouldn't it?

Thanks again!

Comment: You cannot "expect a segmentation fault". There's nothing that allows you to have expectations about what a broken program does.

Comment: I don't understand. Why are you only giving `vel` 1 byte? You need at least 11 bytes to hold a 4-byte unsigned value as a string. Consider the value 4294967295 (max value). That's 10 characters + 1 needed for the terminating null characater.

Comment: I am not writing a string, I am writing a number, it should copy the bytes, not the char, right?

Comment: Why are you using `sprintf` instead of `stringstream`?

Comment: @MagoNick, You created a string with value: "305.0000" from the code `sprintf(vel, "%u%f", n, 5.0);`. When you parsed it using `sscanf(packet, "%u%f", &i, &f);` it reads "`305`" first for integer variable `i` and "`.0000` is left for float variable `f`. Try changing your format strings from `"%u%f"` to `"%u %f"`.

Comment: @xuwicha Thanks! Everything is solved! It was a stupid mistake...

Comment: @clcto I used scanf because I used it before (even if I still make so many mistakes) and I did not know how to use stringsteam

Comment: @MagoNick the same way you use other streams like `cout` and `cin`

Comment: @clcto It actually makes sense to use directly stringstream... beacause I will use it to convert the char array to an actual string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the output of your 1st code is:

```
packet sending: 30
packet dim: 4
```

it's because `sprintf` successfully created a string even though `vel` is 1 byte char array only. Your code produces buffer-overflow on `vel` inside `sprintf`. And probably variable `n` is modified (without you knowing) by this overflow. If you print the value of `n`, I guess it's not `30` anymore.

I'm guessing this is what you want to accomplish on your 1st code:

```
char vel[42];  //42 = 11 + 1 + 14 + 1 + 14 + 1
unsigned int n = 30;
std::sprintf(vel, "%u %.5f %.5f", n, 5.0,6.0);
std::cout<< "packet sending: " << vel << std::endl;
std::cout<< "packet dim: " << strlen(vel)<< std::endl;

//Changes:
//   - add spaces in your format string
//       change "%u%f%f" to "%u %f %f" so sscanf() will know
//       when to stop parsing a specific data.
//   - replace sizeof(vel) with strlen(vel) because
//       your sending a string that changes size.
//       sizeof() is for getting the size of DATA TYPES only.
```

In your receiver code, try changing the format string in your sscanf():

```
std::sscanf(packet, "%u %f", &i, &f);  //add space in the middle.
```

Comment: 'Glad to be of help. :)

Comment: I am noticing now that you allocated 11 bytes for unsigned int, isn't it 4 bytes?

Comment: That's because you're converting int to string when using `sprintf()`. Strings take a lot of bytes because every digits is 1 byte. While the integer is like a counter. String is usually for displaying some text. Integer is a number for processing. The moment you used `sprintf("%d",n)`, you're converting a number to a text. That is a 4 byte number value will be converted to text that could take max of 11 digits (i.e `"-2147483648"`, including the negative sign). Also note that the binary representation of the string `"-2147483648"` is not equal to integer value `-2147483648`.

Comment: Ok, got it. From now on I will be careful with string conversion :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `sprintf` you have to provide buffer large enough to store all characters. Array given in your program is to small, so function overwrites following block of memory, appends `NULL` on the end, and then prints it to stdout correctly. After calling `sprintf` variable `n` is probably not equal to 30. Safer version of this function is `snprintf`. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: Thanks! However if i write a stack big enough and try to retrieve the values it does not work.